# Concatenate videos by pipng to ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to dynamically generate infinite video stream from video clips, so that choose next one on the fly.
I was inspired by [ffplayout project](https://github.com/ffplayout/ffplayout-engine) which [runs `ffplay`](https://github.com/ffplayout/ffplayout-engine/blob/b45df954a49204f129489d4c2d7f3dd73b956420/ffplayout.py#L76) and make it read from stdin, 
and then [runs `ffmpeg`](https://github.com/ffplayout/ffplayout-engine/blob/b45df954a49204f129489d4c2d7f3dd73b956420/ffplayout.py#L114) and stdout is redirected to `ffplay`. It works nice when streaming to rtmp server (probably because there is some buffering applied on the way), but when using `ffplay` you can notice some glitches on video transition.

Video is converted to mpegts for transport through pipe.

I was testing on [this video](https://pixabay.com/videos/tunnel-yellow-abstract-background-12904/) which is made for looping.

In order to eliminate ffmpeg startup, file read delay, I did what follows:

```
# saved raw output
ffmpeg -i tunnel.mp4 -f mpegts tunnel.mpegts
# made fifo.ts
mkfifo fifo
# run ffplay to read from stdin
ffplay -an -f mpegts -i pipe:0 <fifo.ts
# write video to fifo
cat tunnel.mpegts tunnel.mpegts tunnel.mpegts tunnel.mpegts >> fifo.ts
```

still glitches on transition.
I even tried to read video to memory and write to fifo to eliminate disk io

```
def main():
    with open('tunnel.mpegts', 'rb') as fd:
        tunnel = fd.read()

    with open('fifo.ts', 'wb') as fd:
        for _ in range(5):
            fd.write(tunnel)
```

still glitches.

Any idea how to make it work? Maybe another ffmpeg on the way that would buffer/delay/join/transcode?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not the caching, but the fact that ffplay don't get a clean encoded stream.

With your yellow tunnel clip you can try this:

```bash
while true; do
    ffmpeg -i tunnel.mp4 -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 50M -c:a s302m -strict -2 -ar 48k -f mpegts -;
done | ffmpeg -re -i - -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 50M -c:a s302m -strict -2 -ar 48k -f mpegts - | ffplay -
```

And you see, that there is almost no glitches anymore. This is not a really nice solution, but the second ffmpeg instance would recompress the hole stream.

When is just about playing on desktop I would try more somthing like [python-mpv](https://github.com/jaseg/python-mpv).